# Insert X rows into child table based on parent field

Tags: sql, ms-access, triggers, ms-access-2010

Trying to insert a set number of rows into a child table based on a number entered into a parent table

```
parent (licenseID, poolSize)
child (nodeID, licenseID)
```

I was looking into using an After Insert trigger on the parent table but could not figure out how to loop a create record command.

Is this possible to do with macros or should I be looking at VBA code? (MS ACCESS 2010)

Comment: so like if `parent.poolSize = 3` there should be 3 child records? How do you generate `NodeID`?

Comment: Exactly. nodeID is just an auto incremented primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would never enter anything directly into a table.  Giving your users that kind of ability is always going to end up in some form of misery and regret.

I would creat a form to take the number, and then use code behind a "Submit" button to loop the required number of times.  Something like (this code is entirely untested):

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim X as Double

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("Child")

Do for X = 1 to Me.txtNumberOfEntries
   rec.AddNew
   rec("LicenseID") = me.txtLicenseID
   rec.Update
Next X

'Always clear out your variables
Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: FYI, setting objects to `nothing` is not always required (rarely is) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx

Comment: While not required, leaving them open can cause record locking issues, so it's a good idea to get in the habit of doing it.  Setting them equal to nothing will never hurt you.  But not doing so, might.

Comment: Just spent a couple hours making a form...renamed it and then boom, corrupted the database. How would you go about this without forms? Is there a way to call the vba code through a macro?

Comment: Absolutely.  Just use RunCode in a macro.  You have to make it a function in order to do that, because RunCode will only run functions.

Comment: Where is this RunCode? I see RunDataMacro, but not RunCode. I am using Access 2010

Comment: Ah ok I see it, had to create a macro instead of after insert macro

Comment: One more question regarding this. I have the `After Insert macro` running a `RunDataMacro` with the custom Macro I made that has a `RunCode` statement. When double clicking the custom macro which contains the `RunCode` statement, it works fine. However when inserting into the table with the After Insert macro which calls the custom macro...It will not work. I guess the problem is with the After Insert macro not calling the custom macro. Any ideas?